# Docker file AWS Lambda local class import error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a docker container to run in AWS lambda using both local packages and some downloaded using requirements.txt.
Using the documentation, I can successfully create an image with all required external packages like this:

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-python:3.8

# Copy function code
COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY classes ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY class2 ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

COPY requirements.txt  .
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}" --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org
RUN [ "python", "-c", "import nltk; nltk.download('all')" ]


# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

However, I have some local modules that if I try to import when running the app.handler function I get the following error message:  `"Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'classes'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "stackTrace": []}`

I'm copying the directories in the Docker file, so not sure why this would be an issue. For reference my file structure is as:

```
classes/
       email_.py
class2/
       file2.py
app.py
requirements.txt
Dockerfile
```

The following code in app.py causes the issue:

```
from classes.email_ import Email
from class2.file2 import func
```

NOTE: Adding **init**.py files under each folder does not seem to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This change in the dockerfile filed the issue:

```
# Copy function code
...
COPY classes ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/classes
COPY class2 ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/class2
...
```

Comment: fixed it for me too!